# Under what conditions is $f = g^2$ convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, function-and-relation-composition

Suppose that $x \in {\Bbb R}^n$ and $g: {\Bbb R}^n \to {\Bbb R}$. Under what conditions is $f := g^2$ convex?

It can be seen as the composition $f(x) = h(g(x))$ where  $h(y) = y^2$.

---

From page 83 of Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook)

f is convex if h is convex, $\tilde{h}$ is nondecreasing, and g is convex,

f is convex if h is convex, $\tilde{h}$  is nonincreasing, and g is concave,

f is concave if h is concave, $\tilde{h}$  is nondecreasing, and g is concave,

f is concave if h is concave, $\tilde{h}$  is nonincreasing, and g is convex.

Here $\tilde{h}$  denotes the extended-value extension of the function h, which assigns the
value ∞ (−∞) to points not in domain of h for h convex (concave).

---

However, in here, $\tilde{h} = h(y) = y^2$ is not nonincreasing or nondecreasing. Is there any general condition about $g$ that makes $f$ convex?

Comment: $h(y)$ is nonincreasing for $y\leq0$ and nondecreasing for $y\geq0$. So if $g(x) = |x|$ for instance, wouldn't that make $f$ convex?

Comment: Let's assume differentiability for the sake of simplicity. Then you have $f''(x) = h''(g(x))  g'(x)^2 + h'(g(x))g''(x)$. If $h''\geq 0$, the first summand is nonnegative, so you can guarantee $f''\geq 0$ if $h'$ and $g''$ have the same sign. If they don't, you have a sum of positive and negative number, which can be of any sign. Similarly, if $h''\leq 0$, the first summand is nonpositive, so you can guarantee $f''\leq 0$ if $h'$ and $g''$ are of opposite signs, and similarly like before, can't decide if they are of the same sign.

Comment: Now, in your example $h'$ changes signs, but you can restrict domain appropriately so that the sign remains constant.

Comment: If it's not clear, the point I want to make is that even with stricter assumptions such as differentiability and working in $n=1$, you can't really make more general statements than the four listed ones. You'd have to assume some bounds on $h',g',h'',g''$.